# Trying to create a window with two buttons which will each open new windows and close the original window when clicked

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm attempting to create a launch page. I want to open an initial window where the user can either click an 'admin' or 'employee' button which will each open a corresponding window, and close the original window.

So far I'm finding that when clicked the two buttons don't do anything, despite the ActionListener methods in the code below. I'd really appreciate any advice on where I'm going wrong (am a beginner).

*Main*

```
    package deskBooking;

public class Main {
    
 public static void main(String[] args) {  
    LaunchWindow launchWindow = new LaunchWindow();  
    }

}
```

*LaunchWindow*

```
    package deskBooking;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class LaunchWindow implements ActionListener{
// An initial window where users can declare sign in type (Administrator/employee)
// Depending on selection will direct user to an employee or administrator sign in journey
    
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Desk Booking step 1/4");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JButton employeeButton = new JButton("Employee");
    JButton adminButton = new JButton("Admin");
        
    LaunchWindow() {  
    
    frame.setSize(600,300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    
    frame.add(panel);
    
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Welcome to the desk booking system! "+"\n"+"Please declare if you are an admin or a normal user:");
    label.setBounds(50, 20, 80, 25);
    panel.add(label);
        
    panel.add(employeeButton);
    employeeButton.addActionListener(this);
    employeeButton.setBounds(100,160,200,40);
    employeeButton.setFocusable(false);
    
    panel.add(adminButton);
    adminButton.addActionListener(this);
    adminButton.setBounds(100,160,200,40);
    adminButton.setFocusable(false); 
    
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) { 
        
    if(e.getSource()=="employeeButton") {    
        frame.dispose();
        EmployeeWindow employeeWindow = new EmployeeWindow();     
    }
    
    else if(e.getSource()=="adminButton") { 
        frame.dispose();
        AdminWindow adminWindow = new AdminWindow();
    }
  }  
}
```

*EmployeeWindow*

```
    package deskBooking;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class EmployeeWindow {
    
    JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("Employee log-in 2/4");
    JPanel employeePanel = new JPanel();
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Username: ");
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Password: ");
    
    EmployeeWindow(){
    
    frame2.setSize(200,200);
    frame2.add(employeePanel);
    employeePanel.add(label);  
    employeePanel.add(label2);
    
    frame2.setVisible(true); 
    frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    
    }
}
```

*AdminWindow*

```
    package deskBooking;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class AdminWindow {

    JFrame frame3 = new JFrame("Admin log-in 2/4");
    JPanel adminPanel = new JPanel();
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Username: ");
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Password: ");
 
    AdminWindow(){
    
    frame3.setSize(200,200);
    frame3.add(adminPanel);
    adminPanel.add(label);  
    adminPanel.add(label2);
    
    frame3.setVisible(true);   
    frame3.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Generally, your application has one `JFrame`.  You use a `CardLayout` to switch between `JPanels`.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay close attention to the [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) and the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) sections.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc thanks very much, I'll give that a try :)

Comment: I just answered a similar [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70572478/accessing-jpanel-components-from-a-seperate-class/70574171#70574171).

Comment: I appreicate that this program is poor design and I'll re=try using @Gilbert Le Blanc's suggested method.

Could anyone advise why what I've written doesn't work? I can't see why the methods I've defined aren't implemented when my button's are clicked so I feel like I'm possibly missing something very basic...