# Accessing JPanel components from a seperate class

Tags: java, swing

So I want to have a CardLayout class that switches between a menu page and a main app page, but I want to design those two panels in their own classes, then add an ActionListener and a CardLayout in a different class, and have the ActionListener use a button created in one of the panel classes.

Here is a (Not so short) SSCCE that kind of covers what I'm trying to say:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MenuPanel extends Frame{
    JPanel menuPanel;
    JButton login;
    JButton signup;

    public MenuPanel(){
        menuPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        login = new JButton("Login");
        signup = new JButton("Signup");
        
        menuPanel.add(login);
        menuPanel.add(signup);
        
    }
}
```

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MainPanel extends JFrame{
    JPanel menuPanel;
    JButton login;
    JButton signup;

    public MainPanel(){
        mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());=
        
        menuPanel.setBackground(Color.grey);
        
    }
}
```

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CardLayout extends Frame implements ActionL {
//Now how do I add the frames from the other classes so that I can add them to my CardLayout?
CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();
JPanel panelCont;
    public CardLayout() {
        frame.add(panelCont);

        panelCont = new JPanel(cl);
        //Here is where I'm having trouble
        panelCont.add(menuPanel, "1");
        panelCont.add(mainPanel, "2");

        cl.show(panelCont, "1");

        login.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                cl.show(panelCont, "2");
            }
        });
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CardLayout();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use a "observer pattern", this means that the "master" pane is monitoring the "menu" and "main" for desired changes which allow it to make decisions about which view to display

Comment: 1) Use `JFrame` rather than `Frame`. Don't mix AWT & Swing components and windows. 2) But there should be a single frame in an app. All the rest should be `JPanel` containers. 3) There's really no good case here to extend frames or panels. Just use plain instances. 4) *"Here is a (Not so short) SSCCE"* The entire three classes shown above come to 52 lines of code. I would consider 100 LOC to be 'short' as long as it is all necessary to demonstrate the problem, but the SC (self-contained) of SSCCE means it should include the imports for each class, and a `main` method.

Comment: Thank you for producing such a nice, focused SSCCE! :) Glad you got it sorted with the help of ControlAltDel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot add `Frame`s to another component. `Frame` is a top level component with a native peer. You should subclass from something else (JPanel?) instead

Also, btw what you are doing is not good design. Generally, in MVC Swing design, all view and control aspects should be in one class. Don't split the view into multiple classes unless each of those classes stands up as its own reusable widget

Comment: Alright, thank you. I meant for Frame to be a class, but that's definitely not a good name. The only reason that I am doing this in separate classes is because to me it feels more organized, however I will try that, plus it's good to get used to longer, more complex classes.

Comment: @JEKrupat All good to hear. It makes intuitive sense to want to break up the GUI into smaller classes, but it leads you to having multiple controllers (GUI listeners) that are often very hard to connect together.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay close attention to the [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) and the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) sections.

In Java Swing, you create one `JFrame` and as many `JPanels` as you need to create the GUI.

I created a card `JPanel`, a menu `JPanel`, and a login `JPanel` in three separate classes.  The card `JPanel` class creates the `JPanel` with the `CardLayout`.  The menu `JPanel` creates the `JPanel` that contains the menu `JButtons`.  The login JPanel class creates the `JPanel` that contains the login Swing components.

Here's the `JFrame` with the menu `JPanel`.

[image]

Here's the GUI after you left-click on the Login `JButton`.

[image]

Notice how I named the classes.  `CardPanel`, `MenuPanel`, `LoginPanel`.  By appending Panel to the end of the class name, that tells me they **use** a `JPanel`.

When I create a separate `ActionListener` class, I'd name it `ButtonListener` or `SignupListener`.

The only `ActionListener` I created ties the menu login `JButton` to displaying the login `JPanel`.  Since it consists of one line, I made it an anonymous class using a lambda expression.

Here's the complete runnable code.  I made all the additional classes inner classes so I could post this code as one block.  You can and should put these classes in separate files.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class CardLayoutExample implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new CardLayoutExample());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("CardLayout Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(new CardPanel().getPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public class CardPanel {
        
        private final CardLayout cardLayout;
        
        private final JPanel panel;
        
        public CardPanel() {
            this.cardLayout = new CardLayout();
            this.panel = createCardPanel();
        }
        
        private JPanel createCardPanel() {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel(cardLayout);
            panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
            
            panel.add(new MenuPanel(this).getPanel(), "menu");
            panel.add(new LoginPanel().getPanel(), "login");
            
            return panel;
        }
        
        public void showLoginPanel() {
            cardLayout.show(panel, "login");
        }

        public JPanel getPanel() {
            return panel;
        }
        
    }
    
    public class MenuPanel {
        
        private final CardPanel cardPanel;
        
        private final JPanel panel;
        
        public MenuPanel(CardPanel cardPanel) {
            this.cardPanel = cardPanel;
            this.panel = createMenuPanel();
        }
        
        private JPanel createMenuPanel() {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 5, 5));
            panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
            
            JButton login = new JButton("Login");
            login.addActionListener(event -> cardPanel.showLoginPanel());
            panel.add(login);
            
            JButton signup = new JButton("Signup");
            panel.add(signup);
            
            return panel;
        }

        public JPanel getPanel() {
            return panel;
        }
        
    }
    
    public class LoginPanel {
        
        private final JPanel panel;
        
        private final JPasswordField passwordField;
        
        private final JTextField useridField;
        
        public LoginPanel() {
            this.useridField = new JTextField(30);
            this.passwordField = new JPasswordField(30);
            this.panel = createLoginPanel();
        }
        
        private JPanel createLoginPanel() {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
            
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
            gbc.gridwidth = 1;
            
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            JLabel label = new JLabel("Userid:");
            panel.add(label, gbc);
            
            gbc.gridx++;
            panel.add(useridField, gbc);
            
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
            label = new JLabel("Password:");
            panel.add(label, gbc);
            
            gbc.gridx++;
            panel.add(passwordField, gbc);
            
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            gbc.gridwidth = 2;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
            JButton button = new JButton("Submit");
            panel.add(button, gbc);
            
            return panel;
        }
        
        public String getUserid() {
            return useridField.getText();
        }
        
        public char[] getPassword() {
            return passwordField.getPassword();
        }

        public JPanel getPanel() {
            return panel;
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Uses best programming practices. ✔ Honor's the OP's desire to have multiple classes. ✔ Does not extend components unnecessarily. ✔ Uses size hints for text & password fields. ✔ Demonstrates how to use white-space via the layout. ✔ Includes screenshots. ✔  .. Possibly other things that eluded my quick scan.  Nice work Gilbert! 

Comment: Wow! This is  an amazing example and is a huge help to my question, thank you so much for investing the time to create this.